# Graphics - Insert round picture in my CV

Tags: graphics

I need help to

1. make the picture round instead of square and
2. move the picture more to the left.

[image: Here is how it looks now, but I want the picture more to the left and make it round instead of squared.]

Here is some of the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,8 pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{underscore}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\newcommand{\at}{\makeatletter @\makeatother}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{1em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\usetikzlibrary{calc} \node [left] at ($(current page text area.north east)!0.06!(current page text area.south east)$) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{ola.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\par{ {\Huge \textbf{My name}} 
\vspace{0.5cm}\par 
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Email:} & x_x\at gmail.com \\ 
    \textsc{Phone:} & $xx \ xx \ 3x \ x5$ \\
    \textsc{Location:} & xxx, Norway
}{\end{tabular}}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\section{Education}
\begin{longtable}{r|p{14cm}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this with `\clip` and by mixing the top left of the page into your coordinate.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,8 pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{underscore}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\newcommand{\at}{\makeatletter @\makeatother}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{1em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\clip ($(current page text area.north east)!0.06!(current page text area.south east)!0.12!(current page text area.north west)$)
  circle (2cm) node {\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{ola.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\par{ {\Huge \textbf{My name}} 
\vspace{0.5cm}\par 
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Email:} & x_x\at gmail.com \\ 
    \textsc{Phone:} & $xx \ xx \ 3x \ x5$ \\
    \textsc{Location:} & xxx, Norway
}{\end{tabular}}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\section{Education}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess that the photo will change when you compile it on your machine ;-)

**EDIT**: To make my second statement more explicit, I mixed in more of the upper left coordinate, i.e. changed the admixture from `0.12` above to `0.2` in front of `!(current page text area.north west)` here.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,8 pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{underscore}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\newcommand{\at}{\makeatletter @\makeatother}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{1em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\clip ($(current page text area.north east)!0.06!(current page text area.south east)!0.2!(current page text area.north west)$)
  circle (2cm) node {\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{ola.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\par{ {\Huge \textbf{My name}} 
\vspace{0.5cm}\par 
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Email:} & x_x\at gmail.com \\ 
    \textsc{Phone:} & $xx \ xx \ 3x \ x5$ \\
    \textsc{Location:} & xxx, Norway
}{\end{tabular}}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\section{Education}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd EDIT**: OK, this is a quick fix to achieve ``My goal is to put my picture on the left hand side, my name in the center (achieved) and my tabular on the right hand side.''. There are tons of alternative ways of achieving this.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,8 pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{underscore}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\newcommand{\at}{\makeatletter @\makeatother}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{1em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\begin{document}



\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\hspace*{0.4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(ola.center),inner sep=0pt]
\clip (0,0)  circle (2cm) node (ola) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ola.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\centerline{\Huge \textbf{My name}}
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Email:} & x_x\at gmail.com \\ 
    \textsc{Phone:} & $xx \ xx \ 3x \ x5$ \\
    \textsc{Location:} & xxx, Norway
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{0.4cm}\\[0.3cm]
\section{Education}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope that this allows you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Do you also know how I can move the picture more to the left? I managed to make it round, thank you.

Comment: @OlaKristofferNestvold I added a more explicit explanation. Please let me know if this allows you to achieve what you want.

Comment: I must admit that I did not understand what you changed there, I can not find the code (I'm sorry, not the best in latex right now, but I love to learn). Let me say it like this: My goal is to put my picture on the left hand side, my name in the center (achieved) and my tabular on the right hand side.

Comment: @OlaKristofferNestvold Need to go hibernating now, but can give more feedback if needed later.

Comment: Yes, I made it work. Thank you so much for the help, really appreciate it.