# How to put a circular frame to an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I want the circle to come out perfect with white border as the frame of the image, there will be a way to improve the following code

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering 
\caption{Stark Family}
\resizebox{2.3cm}{2cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,draw,white,inner sep=0.27cm,fill overzoom image=Stark.jpg] 
    {};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\label{StarkFamily}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Stark]

Comment: Please make your code compilable? How is `fill overzoom image` defined? Complete code will allow people to understand your question and, hopefully, answer it.

Comment: Perhaps related:https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409261/121799.

Answer (score 6):

You can see the details of the code in [Visual tikz - 4.8 Filling with an image](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf#subsection.4.8); I added some tricks to put image credits using `\rotatebox{}{}` and special fonts for copyright symbol provided by `{fontawesome}` package.

For circular shapes is recommended to use an image with 1:1 aspect ratio.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% PROCESADOR ARARA V3.0
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
pages=some,
firstpage=false,
opacity=0.8,
placement=center,
angle=0,
hshift=0,
vshift=0
]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[scale=.103]{GOT-BG.pdf}}}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \rotatebox{90}{\sf \hspace{2.5cm}\faCopyright\,HBO}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[
            draw=white,fill=white, line width =1.5pt,
            path picture={
                \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                    \includegraphics[height=6cm]{stark}
                };
            }
        ] (0,0) circle (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
    \part{The Starks}
    \lipsum[1-6]        
\end{document}
```

PSD: Code derived from answer in [How to change the background color of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440560/154390) - for the source of the background image: [GOT-BG.pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jy9kpUdGdPzsjQIWnL833NFW12rnAMfz)

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete package superseded by `subfig`. no one is needed in your solution.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to delete that package that is not used in this example, from a previous code that I used, thank you, it is the second time someone mentions it, I will correct it.